# Create React App PWA - change caching strategy of service worker

Tags: reactjs, caching, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have created a PWA template using CRA v4 and enabled the service worker that comes with it by registering it, because I needed to create a pop up notification about installing the PWA.

The lighthouse test has to pass for the app to be PWA compatible so that the browser would fire the `beforeinstallprompt` event listener needed to detect if the user has already installed the PWA or not.

The problem now is that this service worker is using `cache-first` strategy. As a result refreshing the page does not trigger an update and I am left with an older version of the app appearing after I have deployed an update.

**How can I change the caching strategy of CRA v4's service worker such that the user would get a new version of the app by simply refreshing the page?**

I am also interested in knowing why this `cache-first` strategy is used by default. To me it seems bad that the user has to close every tab to get a new version. Why haven't more people brought this up? This is clearly not user friendly...

Answer (score 2):

To change the strategy you need to implement your own code changing service-worker.js and potentially
serviceWorkerRegistration.js. (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies)

I implement my own strategy:
check for updates at the very beginning check for updates each 3 min if there is a update in the very beginning update
cache and refresh the website. if it is after show a popup asking to fresh

serviceWorkerRegistration.ts

```
    /**
     * ...... previous code
     **/
    
    const CHECK_INTERVAL_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 3 // 3 min
    
    function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register(swUrl)
            .then((registration) => {
                registration.onupdatefound = () => {
                    const installingWorker = registration.installing;
                    if (installingWorker == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
                        if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
                            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                                // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
                                // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
                                // content until all client tabs are closed.
                                console.log(
                                    'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                                    'tabs for this page are closed. See https://cra.link/PWA.'
                                );
    
                                // Execute callback
                                if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                                    config.onUpdate(registration);
                                }
                            } else {
                                // At this point, everything has been precached.
                                // It's the perfect time to display a
                                // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                                console.info('Content is cached for offline use.');
    
                                // Execute callback
                                if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                                    config.onSuccess(registration);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                };
    
    
                /****************************
                 start new code
                 *****************************/
                registration.update().then(() => console.debug("Checked for update...")).catch(console.error)
    
                setInterval(() => {
                    console.debug("Checked for update...");
                    registration.update().catch(console.error);
                }, CHECK_INTERVAL_TIME);
    
                /****************************
                 end new code
                 *****************************/
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
            });
    }
```

App.tsx

```
    /**
     * ...... previous code
     **/
    function App() {
        const time = useRef(Date.now()); //can be let, depending of your logic
        useEffect(() => {
            serviceWorkerRegistration.register({
                onSuccess(registration) {
                    console.debug('serviceWorkerRegistration success')
                },
                onUpdate(registration) {
                    console.debug('serviceWorkerRegistration updated',Date.now()-time.current)
                    const  refresh=async ()=>{
                        await registration?.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'}); //send message to update the code (stop waiting)
                        if ('caches' in window) { //delete cache, i think is no necessary but you lose nothing
                            const names = await caches.keys()
                            for (const name of names) {
                                await caches.delete(name)
                            }
                        }
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                    if (Date.now()-time.current<=2000){
                        return refresh()
                    }
                    logicToShowPopup({
                        onClick: refresh
                    })
                }
            })
        }, [])
    
        return (<div>My App</div>)
    }
```

I hope this suits for your  needs